# Microsoft Teams webhook on TFS

Tags: tfs, microsoft-teams

I have discovered Microsoft Teams and I like it. 
I am now trying to trigger pullrequest messages from TFS to Microsoft Teams.
I have a Teams Group webhook url that works fine with curl. 
But when I test it with TFS (Service Hooks -> Web Hooks) then I only get bad requests. 
Do any of you have an idea why that could be?

Comment: Which version of TFS do you have?

Comment: Are you using VSTS (TFS online) or TFS on- premise ? Could you see the "pull request created" in Web Hooks ?

Comment: We have an own inhouse TFS (Version 15.105.25910.0).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using VSTS, you could directly use the **Connectors**  in Microsoft Teams to achieve what you need.

1. Open the Connectors from Teams-General.
2. Add Visual Studio Team Service
3. Add related configuration such as blow picture
   [image]
4. Create a pull request in related VSTS project, will get a message in Microsoft Teams

[image]

If you are using TFS, there is no related add-in for now. Seems you are using  [Incoming Webhook connector](https://dev.outlook.com/Connectors/GetStarted#post-a-card-to-the-webhook) .

For Incoming Webhook, it's only support posts cards. More details about how that card is built, please refer this link: [Actionable Messages Reference](https://dev.outlook.com/actions/reference).

However, for [Web Hooks in TFS](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/service-hooks/services/webhooks), the sent JSON representation is not using the "card type". The sample JSON looks like below:

> ```
> {
>     "event.type": "git.push",
>     ...
>     "messsages": {
>         "text": "...",
>         "html": "...",
>         "markdown": "..."
>     },
>     "detailedMesssages": {
>         "text": "...",
>         "html": "...",
>         "markdown": "..."
>     },
>     "resource": {
>         "id": "...",
>         "url": "https://...",
>         "name": "...",
>         "field1:": "..."
>     }
> }
> ```

So you will get a fail message with bag request(400).

Comment: We are using TFS (not VSTS) together with TFS and I am desperately searching for a way to control the json payload of the Web Hook. I am aware of the possibility to create service hooks programatically but nowhere can I find a way to control the payload format. I can see that there is a drop down of resource versions, baybe that can be extended?

Comment: @EmilG  I' not sure what exactly where is the drop down of resource versions you are talking you could add a screenshot. Is the payload which you are meaning like this http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/158603/what-does-the-term-payload-mean-in-programming ? If so seems no way to control the payload format for now.

Comment: Yes, when I say payload, I am referring to the http body(?)/the json request that is sent through the webhook. The drop down I am referring to is visible when setting up a new service hook (web hook) far down on the page. Anyway I can se when testing out the web hook that the json format is way of from what Teams expects. My plan right now is to write a super simple pub-sub-server that will rewrite the json body and dispatch the message to teams

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you figure it out by now cause obviously the question was asked 3 years ago, but I wanted to post my answer in order to help other people in the future. 
There actually a way to hook TFS with Microsoft Teams yay!!
**From TFS go to Service Hooks --> office 365** instead of (Service Hooks -> Web Hooks) because "Microsoft teams" is part of the suite 365 and as easy as that :). 
**PS: Of course you need to create a channel on Teams first, then click on the 3 dots --> Connectors --> Incoming Webhooks(configure) --> give your hook a name --> Create. And you're done; just copy the link generated by Teams and past it in TFS when u're asked for it** ;)

Comment: we have the tfs 2015 version. I don't see an office 365 service. Is this available on specific tfs versions?

Comment: @NicolasI I think it's related to what Microsoft office suite you're using. My organization is using Office 365. and Teams was newly added to 365 suite. So it seems that u are using office 2016 and teams as a separate application.